# Return rows where the columns match the colours selected EXCEL

Tags: excel, database, indexing, match, rows

I'm fairly certain there's a more elegant way to do this but I can't seem to see it, or if it's staring right in front of me i'm failing to understand it.

I have a table of data in "NEW DB" that lists numbers and blank cells in D4:W and then I have a sheet called "Colour List" where you can select the colours you want to look up, what I then want to happen in "Formulas" section in "Colour List" is to list each formula that contains those particular colours i.e Pure Black and Pure White should return Formulas 3 to 20, Pure Black and Pure Red should Return formulas 42 to 60.

I have a feeling it has something to do with INDEX MATCH MATCH and ROWS and searching for headers but I have no idea how to get them to work as i'm always getting an #N/A error.

It should be noted that this will extend to four searches.

Here's a link to the file, if anyone can help I'd be grateful as it took a while to put this datasheet together

https://mega.nz/file/Oq4xHDCD#6FBZdIVk0Fn8orIiP-DJ2e-ODD_abHtO6k9WwGfJT5c

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lovely workbook. It's really inspiring and fun to see this kind of creations :)!

I haven't solved this with an excel formula as you seem to have quite a few variables and I think it will get more complex with more colours added. Feel free to use my answer or ignore it ;)

However, I want to give you a VBA solution that probably will speed up the workbook since matrix calculations for large workbooks takes time to perform...

Some feedback:

- You have cell settings in the "New DB" worksheet, which makes the workbook 12 mb. Deleting rows from row 15990 to last row, decreases the workbook from 12 to 1,5mb and the workbook is also quite faster.
- PWO, you have a space infront of this word in the "New DB" sheet.
- I would strongly recommed to use vlookup to find the short name of the colour in the sheet "Colour List". To maintain long formulas it's a pain, please see my suggestion in cell A5.
- I took the liberty to restructure some part of your worksheet, I just felt it was somewhat confusing...
- Added short term name for all the colours in the "Sheet1". Personally I think you should rename it to "Mapping sheet" or move the content to settings.

Final word. Amazing work :)!!

---

**Code to calculate Formula Code**

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqw4u3jns06l4lc/complete%20mixing%20guide%20%282%20colours%20only%29%20v0.3b.xlsm?dl=0) to workbook

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate_Formula_Code()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Colour1_Col As Long
Dim Colour2_Col As Long
Dim LastRow_New_DB As Long
Dim Result_Start_Row As Long
Dim Colour_Group_Row As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Colour List") 'Define the Colour list sheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("New DB") 'Define the New DB sheet

Result_Start_Row = 10 'Start from row

LastRow_New_DB = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in the New DB Sheet

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(9, "A"), ws1.Cells(32, "A")).Value = 0 'Clear previous values


If ws1.Cells(5, 2).Value <> "" Then 'If Both Colour 1 and Colour 2 are selected
    Colour1_Col = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(5, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A2:W2"), 0) 'Check which column colour 1 exists in
    Colour2_Col = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(5, 2).Value, ws2.Range("A2:W2"), 0) 'Check which column colour 2 exists in


    For i = 4 To LastRow_New_DB 'Loop from row 4 to last row in the sheet New DB
            If i = 4 And (ws1.Cells(5, 1).Value = "PB" Or ws1.Cells(5, 2).Value = "PB") Then 'Check if any the Colours are black, If yes, then add pure black to 1st row
                    ws1.Cells(Result_Start_Row - 1, "A").Value = ws2.Cells(i, "A").Value
            ElseIf ws2.Cells(i, Colour1_Col).Value <> "" And ws2.Cells(i, Colour2_Col).Value <> "" Then 'Check for the row where there is a value for both of the selected colours
                If i >= 385 Then 'from row 385 the number of rows for a group colour is 19, before it's 18
                    Colour_Group_Row = 18 'How many rows to loop through to add colours
                Else
                    Colour_Group_Row = 19 'How many rows to loop through to add colours
                End If
                For j = i To i + Colour_Group_Row 'For the group, add all the formula code in the Colour list sheet
                    ws1.Cells(Result_Start_Row, "A").Value = ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value 'Copy from New DB sheet to the Colour List sheet
                    Result_Start_Row = Result_Start_Row + 1 'Add one more row for every iteration
                Next j
            Exit Sub
            End If
    Next i

Else 'If only Colour 1 is selected
    Colour1_Col = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(5, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A2:W2"), 0) 'Check which column colour 1 exists in


    For i = 4 To LastRow_New_DB 'Loop from row 4 to last row in the sheet New DB
        If i = 4 And (ws1.Cells(5, 1).Value = "PB" Or ws1.Cells(5, 2).Value = "PB") Then 'Check if any the Colours are black, If yes, then add pure black to 1st row
                ws1.Cells(Result_Start_Row - 1, "A").Value = ws2.Cells(i, "A").Value
        ElseIf ws2.Cells(i, Colour1_Col).Value <> "" Then 'Check for the row where there is a value for both of the selected colours
            If i >= 385 Then 'from row 385 the number of rows for a group colour is 19, before it's 18
                Colour_Group_Row = 18 'How many rows to loop through to add colours
            Else
                Colour_Group_Row = 19 'How many rows to loop through to add colours
            End If
            For j = i To i + Colour_Group_Row 'For the group, add all the formula code in the Colour list sheet
                ws1.Cells(Result_Start_Row, "A").Value = ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value 'Copy from New DB sheet to the Colour List sheet
                Result_Start_Row = Result_Start_Row + 1 'Add one more row for every iteration
            Next j
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End If

MsgBox ("Complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, I've only just begun to dip my toes into VBA and it looks like it should be easily expandable :)

Thank you for the kind words as well, The weorkbook will ultimately get larger as there will be three and four colour code going in as well...though the latter may consist of several as there are around 3 million combinations.

Thank you for the help, it's really appreciated :)

Comment: It's expandable but the more colours the larger the complexity. But please feel free to comment/tag me and I would be happy to at least give it a try :). If you have any question or get stuck with the code, just let me know. Good luck with your project. Amazing work :)